# Regular expression "AND OR" for [left | right] || [top | bottom]

Tags: regex, yacc, lex

I am trying to write a regex that will match the following YACC expression:
`[left | right] || [top | bottom]`:

It should match: (left or right) AND OR (top or bottom). OR '`|`' is simple to do but '`||`' I can't figure it out. 
This expression is part of a CSS gradient grammar defined by W3C:

```
<linear-gradient> = linear-gradient(
    [ [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ] ,]? 
    <color-stop>[, <color-stop>]+
)

<side-or-corner> = [left | right] || [top | bottom]
```

Edit:
Giving: left top
Matched: left top

Giving: left
Matched: left

Giving: right bottom
Matched: right bottom

Giving: right 20px
Matched: right

Hope this explains it better.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want either a side (*left/right/top/bottom*) or a corner (*top-left,bottom-right*...).
This can be solved as something like :

```
/^((left|right|top|bottom)|((top|bottom)delimiter(left|right)))$/
```

you can, of course, reverse the order of the sides for corner notation (to output corners as *left-top* and not *top-left*)  :

```
/^((left|right|top|bottom)|((left|right)delimiter(top|bottom)))$/
```

Note that delimiter is your desired delimiter (can be an empty space or a minus sign).
Hope this helps!

P.S. : I heard your call for help on twitter :P.

**update**
based on your edit, I think now I understand what you need :

```
/^((left|right|top|bottom)|((left|right|(-?\d*(\.\d+)?(px|em|\%)))\s+(top|bottom|(-?\d*(\.\d+)?(px|em|\%)))))$/
```

This regex now matches a side (*left/top/right/bottom*) or two sides defined by left & top values, which can be either the direction keywords (*left/top/right/bottom*) or an actual value (such as `100px` or `1.4em`).
The value regex (`-?\d*(\.\d+)?(px|em|\%)`) matches any floating number (even without the first zero : `.123` instead of `0.123`) followed by a unit of measurement (here you can supply a full list of units)

Here's some of my (javascript) test which passed:

```
var pattern = /^((left|right|top|bottom)|((left|right|(-?\d*(\.\d+)?(px|em|\%)))\s+(top|bottom|(-?\d*(\.\d+)?(px|em|\%)))))$/;
pattern.test('left bottom');   // true
pattern.test('-10px top');     // true
pattern.test('-.23em 140%');   // true
```

**final update**

- removed the start & end characters
- switched the order of the side and corner patterns, prioritizing the corner pattern to match first

`/(((left|right|(-?\d*(\.\d+)?(px|em|\%)))\s+(top|bottom|(-?\d*(\.\d+)?(px|em|\%))))|(left|right|top|bottom))/`

Comment: Thanks for the help :) It should actually just match left and top. Check out my edit.

Comment: http://regexr.com?31eib in this case it works. However if you replace bottom with something else (not a number) it does not. So "left bottom" matches "left bottom", this is right. "left somethingelse" should match just "left"

Comment: ok, well then just eliminate the `^` and `$` characters : `/((left|right|top|bottom)|((left|right|(-?\d*(\.\d+)?(px|em|\%)))\s+(top|bottom|(-?\d*(\.\d+)?(px|em|\%)))))/` .  this will allow you to have `somethingelse` before or after your desired matches and still pass the test.

Comment: Sorry, now it doesn't match 'left bottom'. Just matches 'left' :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/(left|right)|(top|bottom)|(left|right)\s(top|bottom)/
```

should do the task. You might shorten it to

```
/(left|right|top|bottom)|(left|right)\s(top|bottom)/
```

or

```
/(left|right)|((left|right)\s)?(top|bottom)/
```

Comment: Looks like only the first 'left' is matched. It should be: left and top. Check it out: http://regexr.com?31ehs

Comment: OK, that would need a ^ and $... As in gion13s answer.